# How does the Intellij Idea change the scope of dependencies?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I found this function in Project Structure in Intellij Idea:

[image]

It seems that this UI can manually  change the scope of the dependencies. However I found that it does not change the pom.xml file, so how can it manages to change the scope?

Besides, what is the corresponding operation in Linux?

Comment: Do you already have a pom?

Comment: @Makoto Yes and in fact this is the source code of Spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular view is geared more towards projects which lack dependency management from something like Maven or Gradle, and will not interfere with either.  In fact, this particular listing is built *based* on those dependencies and exclusions.

If you want to change the scope of your dependencies in a project that already contains Maven and Gradle, look to do so in their respective files (`pom.xml` / `build.gradle`).